# why can't I pass companion object to a function

Tags: scala, silhouette

I am working on Silhouette framework and am creating an variable of type `Environment`. It's companion object has signature

```
def apply[E <: Env](
  identityServiceImpl: IdentityService[E#I],
  authenticatorServiceImpl: AuthenticatorService[E#A],
  requestProvidersImpl: Seq[RequestProvider],
  eventBusImpl: EventBus
```

For the `authenticatorServiceImpl` parameter, I thought that I could pass the companion object `SessionAuthenticatorService` (as defined in `https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/authenticators/SessionAuthenticator.scala`) but when I tried:

```
val sessionEnv = com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[SessionEnv](new UserService(userRepository),SessionAuthenticatorService() ,CredentialsProvider(),EventBus())
```

I get the error

> com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.SessionAuthenticatorService.typ does not take parameters.

I removed the `()` but got another error:

> found : SessionAuthenticatorService.type [error] required: AuthenticatorService[components.SessionEnv#A]

It seems my concepts are not sound. Why I cannot pass `SessionAuthenticatorService`?

Comment: so I'm not familiar with any of these frameworks but a word generally on companion objects. You can think of them like static class members (fields and methods with the static key word in java e.g.) so the object containing these members is actually not of the type of that particular class. 

E.g. you have some class `Foo` the companion object of that class `Foo` is not of type `Foo` but has it's own (mostly irrelevant type)

Comment: Thanks Dominic. Your answer was also correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A companion object is not an instance of the companion class. It is actually a different type.

```
class ABC(val arg: Int)
object ABC

val abc: ABC      = new ABC(9)
val xyz: ABC.type = ABC

abc.arg  //res0: Int = 9
xyz.arg  //Error: value arg is not a member of object A$A1661.this.ABC
```